# HTML form POST data not transferring to next page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a drop-down box.  The user selects an option from the dropdown box and hits submit.  On submit, a new page opens up with a new form.  The option that was selected is not being transferred to the next page.  My form code is:

```
<form method="post" action="hero_modify_form.php">
    <div>
        <label>Select a hero to add or modify:  </label>
        <select name="heroname" type="input">
            <option></option>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
            <option>
            <?php echo $row['Hero_Name'] ?>
            </option>
<?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="heroname">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The next page loads and displays some test variables at the top, but the variable from the POST is empty.  My code on the page is

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('header.php');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $_POST['heroname'];
echo $username;
$test1 = "test 1, before the if statement";
echo $test1;
```

I get no errors on the page.  The username variable and the test1 variable echo normally.  The heroname variable doesn't.  I need help figuring out why the selection from the form is not transferring to the next page.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `<select>` element does not have a `type` attribute. Try removing `type="input"` from `<select name="heroname" type="input">` and see if that clears the issue up

Comment: Your options doesn't have a value attribute. The value of the selected option will be posted. And also what @RiggsFolly said, a select tag does not need a type attribute.

Comment: This is basically 3 typos

Comment: And also DO NOT CHANGE THE QUESTION AFTER IT HAS BEEN ANSWERED it makes the answer look ridicululous

Answer (score 1):

1. You have forgotten the `value` attribute from the `<option>` elements. Whatever is in the `value` attribute is what is returned to the server script.
2. You have a `type="input"` attribute on the `<select>` element, that does not belong there.
3. You have called the button `<button type="submit" name="heroname">` which is also what you called the dropdown `<select name="heroname">` you cannot use the same name more than once. So change the button name to something else like `<button type="submit" name="submithero">` for example

```php
<form method="post" action="hero_modify_form.php">
    <div>
        <label>Select a hero to add or modify:  </label>
        <select name="heroname">
            <option></option>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['Hero_Name'] ?>">
            <?php echo $row['Hero_Name'] ?>
            </option>
<?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="submithero">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry.  I have spent two days researching online, especially this site, reviewing similar issues that other people have had.  I've found nothing that has helped.

Comment: Hi Allan, that comment was to the person providing this rather less than helpful answer

Comment: And what have you done **in this Answer** to fix something? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: Thanks, @RiggsFolly I'm added explain

Comment: @Ramil...  I tried that.  no change.

Comment: @Allan im added comment on the top you try  this code  <option value="<?php echo $row['Hero_Name'] ?>">

Comment: I updated the code in my original question to show the value attribute added to the option.  The page still does not pass the information to the next page.

Comment: @Allan I'm forgot remove type="input" thanks for RiggsFolly remove this is attribute

Comment: Hope you dont mind, you had 2 of the 3 errors, so it seemed easier to add the last one to your answer instead of create one of my own

Comment: I changed the name of the submit button so that it does not conflict with the option name.  The page is still not passing the information to the next page.  I even close my browser, clear the cache, and login to the website again.

Answer (score -2):

the button does not need a name attribute

```
<form method="post" action="hero_modify_form.php">
        
            <div>
                <label>Select a hero to add or modify:  </label>
                <select name="heroname">
                    <option></option>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['Hero_Name'] ?>">
                            <?php echo $row['Hero_Name'] ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```